# Rails plugin/Gem for a multiselect form textbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems, multi-select

Does anyone know of a good plugin or gem that lets you enter multiple selections into a single form textbox? I have two models, "Things" and "Categories", and I want to be able to select and enter in multiple Categories from the database when creating a new Thing. I've found a few multiselect plugins, but they apparently only allow you to select from specified options that you have to provide in the form. Preferably, such a plugin/gem would also have an autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ran across this or if it applies to you, but you might check out the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.

Your description is a bit vague so I don't know if this helps, but I certainly hope that it does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was thinking more of something like '<%= f.collection_select :thing %>', something that would allow me to set multiple @thing.categories with one form textbox.